# Incorporating denominator uncertainty into a proportion

Tags: confidence-interval, uncertainty, epidemiology, error-propagation

I am calculating an incidence risk (r): number of cases of a disease in a population over one year (c) divided by the total mid-year population (N).

$$
r = \frac{c}{N}
$$

Let's assume that c is a precise measure, with no uncertainty around it.

N, however, is a point estimate. I also have a 95% CI around it:

$$
N=125
$$

$$
(u(N),v(N))=(100,150)
$$

Can I incorporate this uncertainty into the risk, in order to calculate a 95% CI around r?

This is not something I've ever done. After some online searching, I've come across error propagation, that I think would apply here - error propagation for a quotient.

$$
\sigma_r = |r| \sqrt{(\frac{\sigma_c}{c})^2 + (\frac{\sigma_N}{N})^2 + 2\frac{\sigma_{cN}}{cN}}
$$

However, I'm not sure:

1. If this is appropriate to use in this circumstance
2. How to go from a confidence interval to `sigma_{N}` and `sigma_{cN}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In your case, $\sigma_c$ and $\sigma_{cN}$ equal zero, as $c$ is measured without error.  But actually, there's a simpler approach...
2. Since the function $1/N$ is monotonic, a valid 95% confidence interval of $1/N$ is just equal to a 95% confidence interval of $N$ run through the function $1/N$.  So your 95% CI of $N$ would be $(1/150, 1/100)$, and the associated 95% CI of $c/N$ is $(c/150, c/100)$.